# Responsive iframe containing responsive content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

There are many articles out there discussing a clever way in CSS to make videos (such as youtube) delivered through an iframe responsive (such as described here https://blog.theodo.fr/2018/01/responsive-iframes-css-trick/).  Ultimately you wrap your iframe in a relative container with a top padding equal to the aspect ratio (height/width * 100)% of the video.

This works great when your aspect ratio of the iframe contents is static, but is there a clever way to achieve this purely through CSS if your **iframe content** is also responsive?

For example lets say your iframe contents contain a bootstrap grid of boxes (col-xs-12 col-md-3) and you assign 100% width to the iframe so it responds to vertical window resizing of the parent.  As you decrease the size of the parent, at the point the col-xs-12 kicks in, the aspect ratio has changed and you are probably going to see a vertical scrollbar appear for the iframe due to the height change.

I think the only way to achieve responsiveness in this case is through javascript (postMessage calls).

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you need a special style tag in the iframe.
I am not sure if I understood ou Q correctly though, so the ans may be inaccurate. can you make it shorter?